# Three tables that are related in some ways need to be plotted on map as markers. Best way to generate JSON files to plot them?

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In a bit of a dilemma. I have tables **Schools**, **Projects**, **Sponsors**.

**Schools** and **Projects** have a join/associative table (**Schools** have done some **Projects**). **Sponsors** and **Projects** too (**Sponsors** sponsored certain **Projects** that were done by certain **Schools**). So, they are all related/connected. Later on, I want to use this inter-connectivity for filtering with a bunch of forms controls.

All three tables (**Schools**, **Projects**, **Sponsors**) have latitude and longitude columns.

Using JSON, I want to plot all three as markers on my map (Google Maps API v3) and show, in some way, how they are connected. I'm using this [Google Maps v3 plugin for jQuery](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) at the moment.

So, there will be three types of markers on the map when it initializes - **Schools** (name, address, phone, types of specializations of the school, completed projects, etc.), **Projects** (name, description, area of specialization), **Sponsors** (name, address, phone, sponsored projects, etc.).

The filtering will be based on 'types of specializations'(will show all schools with selected types of specializations, all the projects they did, and all the sponsors for each project ) and ' area of specialization '( will show all the projects with selected area of specialization, all the schools that did these projects and all sponsors associated with each project ).

**The problem is** I'm not sure how to approach the generation of JSON file (or files?) and their structure.

Should I generate three different JSON files for each table (**Schools**, **Projects**, **Sponsors**) which will contain data along with the location (lat, lng) to plot them as markers.

*OR*

Should I have one huge JSON file generated, let's say, based on **Schools** which will contain **Projects** child nodes which in turn will contain **Sponsors** child nodes?

*OR*

How would you approach this problem?

So far I've managed to plot all the schools as markers on my map:

```
$(function(){
    $('#map_canvas').gmap(mapOptions).bind('init', function() {
        $.getJSON( 'results.json', function(data) {                         
            $.each(data.schools, function(i, s) {                           
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(s.Lat, s.Lng),
                    'bounds':true
                }).click(function() {                               
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                        'content': '<h1>'+s.SchoolName+'</h1>'+
                        '<p style="color: green">'+s.SchoolAddress+'</p>'
                    }, this);                           
                });                     
            });                 
        });             
    });         
});
```

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you aren't looking for code to query the database and actually create the JSON; you want to focus on the actual structure of the JSON and how it may be handled at the client using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I approached this (and it *worked*) was the following:

Instead of generating one (or three separate) `JSON` file(s) that contained the data from all three tables, I simply generate an SQL query, which is built depending on what the user wants to see on the map.

So if the user wants to see only **Schools** - build an SQL query which grabs only **Schools** from the database and formats the data (name, address, phone, types of specializations of the school, completed projects, etc.) into `JSON` format on-the-fly.

If the user wants to see more than one type of the marker on the map(e.g. **Schools** and their **Projects**) - just build up SQL query which uses `JOIN` to grab the data about the **Schools**, **Projects**, and their relationship data which can be used to link every school to appropriate **Projects** (**Schools** `infobox` have two tabs - *School Info* and *Projects Done* ) and vice versa.

Comment: Nice. I can tell from reading your description that you used sweat and hard work to find the right solution. Good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

JSON generation is pretty simple. JSONs are just strings formatted in such a way that they can be sent between different platforms and decoded into something usable like an array.

As for the formatting, maybe you could make another table of latitude/longitude as Primary Key, to keep track of what each lat/long location has associated with it (i.e. school/project/sponsor).

So you have:

```
Location | School     | Project     | Sponsor
---------|------------|-------------|----------
12/46    | Hoover Elem| Science Fair| NULL
37/87    | NULL       | Recycling   | GreenSponsor
45/32    | Lonely High| NULL        | NULL
```

etc. This way you can query this table to map the relationships relative to each location.

You should be able to generate that table automatically if each element (school/project/sponsor) has the Location, by using a crafted SELECT statement

edit: Even if it's not as simple as "select all names from these three tables with the same location" you should be able to pick one location (I'd assume school), then fill in any relationships based on "specialization" or "completed project" that school shares with a project, and if any of those exist, check if there are sponsors that relate to those projects.

Comment: Hmm. The `Location` column - on who is it based on?( Schools or Projects or Sponsors location? ). Because Schools, Projects and Sponsors all have different locations.

Comment: Ah, you should still be able to find a way to generate a table with their relational mappings, even if location isn't the best way to do it. But from the sounds of it, you'll want a location to generate as the pin (so that you have one pin with any multiple relationships) Which location to use is up to you, depending on what would be the clearest way to communicate it. Off the top of my head, I'd guess "school" is the best place to put a pin and show its relation to projects and sponsors

Comment: Are you saying that the `Location` in your table should be based on Schools location? Then use Projects and Sponsors location to plot them relative to the School's locations?

Comment: That sounds about right, but I'm not 100% on exactly what the problem is that you're trying to solve

Comment: Well, I want to plot Schools, Projects and Sponsors on the map(all three of them have their own latitude and longitude columns). The problem I have is deciding how to structure JSON. You suggested to use one big JSON with the focus on Schools which will have projects as children and Sponsors children of Projects. But will it be able to handle any sorts of filtering?

Comment: JSON is just formatting for the data you're sending, so you'll want to be able to generate a list of what locations should be marked under which filtering conditions, format that into a JSON, and ship it to Google. How to do that filtering depends on how the rest of your project works, which I don't know, but you should be able to generate the filters via dynamic SQL queries (i.e. "SELECT location FROM Schools INNER JOIN Projects ON school.specialization = project.specialization WHERE project.specialization = math" will give you all schools that share a math specialization with projects